# How to always show all apps in Dash?

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-dash

I have Oneiric running in Virtualbox with Unity (3D), it's up todate as of now. When I go to the Dash to find an app I have to click a small arrow to show all the apps in that category.

[image: Dash - Show more apps]

Once I click it, it shows all the apps during the current session. However, after rebooting I have to click the arrow again to show all apps.

Is there anything I could do to save this 'Show all apps' settings permanently?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at least for now ,it is hardly coded in unity ,To it you have to create a patch for unity